# Immediately redirect to logout page when session expires without manually refreshing page

Tags: session, jsf, redirect, jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.0 in my project and I want redirect to logout page after session expired. I try method in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246535/redirecting-to-login-when-session-timeout-in-jsf-spring-or-automatic-logout-when) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543094/how-to-redirect-to-index-page-if-session-time-out-happened-in-jsf-application)
. It doesn't work. Redirect me to logout page only after I refresh page. I want do it automatically. How do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543094/how-to-redirect-to-index-page-if-session-time-out-happened-in-jsf-application

Comment: @cjslv Do you read my post?

Comment: oh sorry about that, I didn't notice the links.

Comment: @cjslv Is it possible in JSF ?

Comment: have you tried using primefaces? Take a look at the `poll` component here https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml

Comment: @cjslv What in case when I have two tab in browser with my app?

Comment: @BalusC how this topic from duplicated can help ?