# Auto Log Off once the session expires

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

Our application logs off after 30 min and gets redirected to login page,i am specifying session timeout in web.xml and using a requestProcessor for redirecting.I want to show to the user a message saying your session got expired once the session expires,how can i do that.Auto log off ?
I would like to prompt the error message on the page"The session is timeout, please login again" . Then how could I detect the session is timeout? will any methods trigger automatically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an activity checker which checks every minute if any user activity has taken place (mouseclick, keypress) and performs a heartbeat to the server side to keep the session alive when the user is active and does nothing when the user is not active. When there is no activity for 30 minutes (or whatever default session timeout is been set on server side), then perform a redirect.

Here's a kickoff example with little help of [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to bind click and keypress events and fire ajax request.

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.active = false;
        $('body').bind('click keypress', function() { $.active = true; });
        checkActivity(1800000, 60000, 0); // timeout = 30 minutes, interval = 1 minute.
    });

    function checkActivity(timeout, interval, elapsed) {
        if ($.active) {
            elapsed = 0;
            $.active = false;
            $.get('heartbeat');
        }
        if (elapsed < timeout) {
            elapsed += interval;
            setTimeout(function() {
                checkActivity(timeout, interval, elapsed);
            }, interval);
        } else {
            window.location = 'http://example.com/expired'; // Redirect to "session expired" page.
        }
    }
</script>
```

Create a `Servlet` which listens on `/heartbeat` and does basically just the following:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    request.getSession();
}
```

to keep the session alive.

When you store the logged-in user in the session, it will be "automagically" logged out whenever the session expires. So you don't need to manually logout the user.

Comment: I want the alert message to be displayed after 30mins,how can i alter the above script,i have defined the session time out in web.xml

Comment: This Script shows the pop up even if the application is in use.

Comment: That may indeed happen when you've multiple windows open in the same session. It was a basic kickoff example. You'll need to go some steps further. Fire ajaxical polls to the server side to keep the session alive as long as the user is active. You can find an example in [this other answer of me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319020/mvc-with-jquery-handling-session-expire/2319211#2319211).

Comment: Not specifically. You can also use plain JS for it (jQuery itself is also "just" JavaScript). It's only going to be more code.

Comment: Do u have any script for it?I am not aware of ajax so not getting it clearly

Comment: Just add `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>` to your HTML `<head>` and all jQuery code will work. They also have tutorials at their homepage http://jquery.com.

Comment: @BalusC - this wont serve the purpose when we do some server side work with AJAX... so this solution is not full proof....

Comment: @BalusC- i know the probable solution but thought of adding this comment just for reference of people who may refer to this solution blindly for there use.

Comment: then we dont need to use servlet `$.get('heartbeat');`. @BalusC

Answer (score 2):

Create a Listener class implementing `HttpSessionListener` and define it in web.xml

This will notify you when any session is destroyed. Use the `sessionDestroyed()` method.

See a full example here:

http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/

Comment: The above solution will force the application to prompt the message even after logout,it will not check expiry time say 30 mins and show the message

Answer (score 1):

Either it may be simple servlet, spring-mvc or spring-security  auto logout is not possible without perfect client side logic.
Considering application will have both type of request

- AJAX and
- form submission/page reload

Auto logout needs very calculated logic. Presenting my autologout functionality implementation with following

### Advantages.

---

1. No extra call/request is used to achieve this. considering performance impact if more than 10k active users and extra calls to achieve auto logout.
2. One line configuration using  tag.
3. Works flawlessly even if user opens multiple tab or multiple window.
4. It intimates you before 30 seconds of session invalidation, so if you have filled form and not submitted, you can keep session alive(extend session by one click). So user less likely to loose unsaved data.

### Usage

---

**1. Include auto logout script in required JSP pages as given below.**

```html
    ....
    </body>
    <jsp:include page="../template/autologout-script.jsp"></jsp:include>
</html>
```

**2. Create a JSP page, autologout-script.jsp and add below code.**
Note: No  editing/configuring is required

```html
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var timeOutTimeInSeconds = ${ timeOutTimeInSeconds }; 
    var showTimerTimeInSeconds= ${ showTimerTimeInSeconds };

    var sessionCheckIntervalId = setInterval(redirectToLoginPage, timeOutTimeInSeconds * 1000);
    var timerDisplayIntervalId = setInterval(showTimer, (timeOutTimeInSeconds - showTimerTimeInSeconds) * 1000);
    var badgeTimerId;
    window.localStorage.setItem("AjaxRequestFired", new Date());

    function redirectToLoginPage(){
        //location.href =  '<c:url value="/" />'+'${loginPageUrl}';
        window.location.reload();
    }

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        resetTimer();
    });

    $(window).bind('storage', function (e) {
         if(e.originalEvent.key == "AjaxRequestFired"){
             console.log("Request sent from another tab, hence resetting timer")
             resetTimer();
         }
    });

    function resetTimer()
    {
        showTimerTimeInSeconds= ${ showTimerTimeInSeconds };

        console.log("timeOutTimeInSeconds : "+timeOutTimeInSeconds)
        window.localStorage.setItem("AjaxRequestFired", new Date());

        window.clearInterval(sessionCheckIntervalId);
        sessionCheckIntervalId = setInterval(redirectToLoginPage, timeOutTimeInSeconds * 1000);

        window.clearInterval(timerDisplayIntervalId);
        timerDisplayIntervalId = setInterval(showTimer, (timeOutTimeInSeconds - showTimerTimeInSeconds) * 1000);

        hideTimer();
    }

    function showTimer()
    {
        $('#sessionTimeRemaining').show();
        $('#sessionTimeRemainingBadge').html(showTimerTimeInSeconds--);
        window.clearInterval(timerDisplayIntervalId);
        badgeTimerId = setInterval(function(){
            $('#sessionTimeRemainingBadge').html(showTimerTimeInSeconds--);
        }, 1000);
    }

    function hideTimer()
    {
        window.clearInterval(badgeTimerId);
        $('#sessionTimeRemaining').hide();
    }
});
</script>
```

**3. Configure session attributes to configuring timeout setting**
Note: Configure this after session creation. You can implement HttpSessionListener sessionCreated method and set the following configuration as per your requirement.

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(300);

session.setAttribute("timeOutTimeInSeconds", 300);
session.setAttribute("showTimerTimeInSeconds", 30);
```

**4. Add below html for displaying timer.**
Note: it can be moved to autologout-script template page if you are good at CSS. Hence you can avoid to add this in each and every page.
Include bootstrap or add your custom css.

```
<span class="badge badge-primary" title="click to keep session alive" id="sessionTimeRemaining" 
    onclick="ajaxSessionRefresh()" style="display:none;">
    <i class="badge badge-danger" id="sessionTimeRemainingBadge" style="float:left">30</i>
     &nbsp; 
     <small>Refresh</small>
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
</span>
```

[image]

That is all about a simple auto logout implementation.
You can download working example from my github repository
[Autologout using simple servlet example](https://github.com/nlpraveennl/stackoverflow-answer-reference/tree/master/servletproject-autologout)
[Autologout using spring-security java configuration example](https://github.com/nlpraveennl/stackoverflow-answer-reference/tree/master/springsecurity-autologout-javaconfig)
[Autologout using spring-security xml configuration example](https://github.com/nlpraveennl/stackoverflow-answer-reference/tree/master/springsecurity-autologout-xmlconfig)

### Logic Explained

---

**Case 1: On Page load**
Here logic is simple, on page load set timer of interval equlas to maxInactiveInterval. after timeout redirect to login page.
**Case 2: Keep track AJAX calls**
Now considering AJAX requests, you can use .ajaxStart() or .ajaxComplete() callbacks of jquery so that if any ajax request is fired you can reset the interval.
**Case 3: Tracking multi tab/window activity**
Intertab communication is done to synchronize state of each tab. Used localStorage on change event.

*Limitations/Improvements required*
1. If maximum allowed session is one, if session is taken from another system, AJAX request will fail. It needs to be handled to redirect to login page.
2. Use ajaxStart() instead of ajaxComplete() to have exact sync of idleTime values between server and browser.

*Requirements*
1. Jquery

## Alternatives to current implementation compared

---

1. **Setting Refresh header** in http response. *(Not works for AJAX requests)*

```
response.setHeader("Refresh", "60; URL=login.jsp");
```

2. **Setting meta refresh tag** in HTML *(Not works for AJAX requests)*

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60; url=login.jsp">
```

3. **Configuring Activity checker**
   Keeps session alive by repeated AJAX request. Tracks idle time and makes logout request after timeout.
   No doubt it is a good one with simple logic. But i want to just ink my observations.

   - **Performance impact** if 2 requests are made per minute to keep session alive and 50k active users. 100k requests per minute.
   - **Intertab communication** If two tabs are open, one tab is receiving activity but other tab is not receiving activity, that tab fires logout request and invalidate session even though activity is present in other tab. (But can be handled)
   - **Force logout approach** It is a client is dominated over server to invalidate session.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using servlet sessions, you can check to see if the session the jsp / servlet is returning is new using the isNew() method. If yes, then the user's session has expired and you can display the relevant messages.

Comment: user session expire message has to be shown only after the time out ,in your case it will display even after logout ,which i dont need

Answer (score 0):

Include a javascript utility function inside your JSP and ping the server every 31 minutes.
The above mentioned utility function should be using setTimeout() JS function internally.

```
setTimeout ( "checkServerSession()",  /* intervalInMilliSeconds */ 31000);
```

Note that

> checkServerSession()

is a regular JS function which may fire HTTP requests. If the request is successful session exists otherwise show the prompt to the user.

Comment: Let me know an example ,how can this be functioned