# How to detect session timeOut expired using spring security?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, spring-security

how to detect and redirect page  when the timeout expires in a JSF application without navigation. My application contains one xhtml page only. and  how to adjust the timeout?

Comment: This may be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201991/auto-log-off-once-the-session-expires

Comment: @BalusC there is a way to do this with spring configuration?

Comment: @BalusC the js link <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> is not valid

Comment: I don't do Spring. But in theory, it is in any way irrelevant here if you're using Spring or not. This is a pure client side solution with help of an extremely simple servlet which should run as good in a Spring flavored webapp.

Comment: @berber5 the link to jquery in the BalusC worked for me. Use the full url (including the` http://` at the beginning). Also, your question doesn't need to be solved by a server framework but with a simple Servlet.

Comment: thank you my friends, its work but without using servlet. I just do this `window.location = 'http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/j_spring_security_logout';` @BalusC @Luiggi Mendoza

Comment: @BalusC the code dosent work in chrome !!!!

Comment: Apparently you modified it too much without actually understanding how it works. It works fine for me in all browsers.