# Restriction on number of opened tabs

Tags: javascript, jsp, web, struts2, browser-tab

There are some links on web-page.

On right click there is option of 'open link in new tab'(browser option).

I want to restrict user for not opening more that two tabs?
How can i do this?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://localhost:8080/struts_tab/abcForm1.action" oncontextmenu="return false;"><span>First Click[Right Click disabled]</span></a></li>
<li><a href="http://localhost:8080/struts_tab/defForm2.action"><span>Second clieck[Not more than 2 tabs]</span></a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't restrict the user from *opening* a new tab.
<sub>(This reminds me the old pop-ups with no buttons, no address bar, but still responding to backspace and other events)</sub>

You can however make your app **recognize the attempt of opening a third tab**, and load a different result like an error message, for example:

> Maximum open tabs limit reached. Please use no more than two tabs concurrently. <kbd>close this tab</kbd>

To do this, you can use [HTML5 **sessionStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage).
<sub>Note: **Web Storage** (`sessionStorage` and `localStorage`) [is supported on every browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) nowadays.</sub>

> #### sessionStorage
>
> This is a global object (`sessionStorage`) that **maintains a storage area
>   that's available for the duration of the page session**. A page session
>   lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page
>   reloads and restores. **Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause
>   a new session to be initiated**.

Then you can

- if not present in sessionStorage, generate an unique token in JSP, and put it in sessionStorage,

  ```js
  $(function(){
      // Read the ID. If it's null, this is a new tab: 
      // generate the ID and store it for later.
      var tabId = sessionStorage.getItem("tabId");
      if (tabId == null){
          tabId = Math.random();
          sessionStorage.putItem("tabId",tabId);
      }
  ```
- send it back to the action

  ```js
      // Add the ID to the form (as hidden field), 
      // so it will be posted back in next submission.
      $('<input>').attr('type'  , 'hidden')
                  .attr('name'  , 'tabId')
                  .attr('value' , tabId)
      .appendTo('form');
  });
  ```

  , maybe to a setter in a BaseAction, extendend by the other actions, and read by `prepare()`, or **much better in an Interceptor**;
- put it in a collection checking that it doesn't contain already two elements, otherwise return the error result, that should be mapped globally:

  ```
  public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
      Action action = (Action) actionInvocation.getAction();
      if(action instanceof LimitedTabsAware){ //interface to identify special actions
          ActionContext context = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext();
          Map<String, String[]> request = ((HttpServletRequest) 
                              context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST)).getParameterMap();

          if (request.containsKey("tabId")){              
              String tabId = (String) request.get("tabId")[0];
              List<String> openTabs = context.getSession().get("OPEN_TABS_KEY");

              if (openTabs.contains(tabId)){
                  return actionInvocation.invoke();                   
              } else if (openTabs.size()>=2){
                  return "tabLimitExceeded"; // global result
              } else {
                  openTabs.add(tabId);
                  context.getSession().put("OPEN_TABS_KEY", openTabs);
                  return actionInvocation.invoke();
              }

          } else {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no tabId in this request.");
          }
      } else {
          return actionInvocation.invoke();
      }
  }
  ```

Then you should find a way to recognize when a tab get closed (to free one slot), by either:

- [timizing the period of validity of the elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26911658/1654265) in your collection (if you don't use a tab for some time, the session expires, and so must do the token in the collection)
- otherwise, putting a [javascript AJAX timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3203250/1654265) in your page (eg. every 30 seconds), that send a *`keep-alive`* signal to an action to refresh the validity of the element. If the tab get closed, the signal is not sent anymore.