# Prevent spider from racking up Tomcat sessions

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlets

I've got a fairly new website (~3 weeks old) running on Tomcat w/so far pretty low numbers of visitors.

For the last week I've noticed 1,000+ active sessions, and checking Tomcat's localhost_access* logs show that the
overwhelming majority are coming from IPs in this range: 119.63.196.* which all look to belong to Baidu Japan.

Here's a small example from the logs of them hitting the front page.
119.63.196.107 - - [24/Aug/2011:07:02:46 +0000] "GET /;jsessionid=94085F76780ACFD96C8109A29446288D HTTP/1.1" 200 10311
119.63.196.44 - - [24/Aug/2011:07:03:21 +0000] "GET /;jsessionid=943133C77BB1756CF11592115BA81725 HTTP/1.1" 200 10333
119.63.196.39 - - [24/Aug/2011:07:03:56 +0000] "GET /;jsessionid=9B4384BDECF540C8628467F7AB4AB463 HTTP/1.1" 200 10311
119.63.196.19 - - [24/Aug/2011:07:04:31 +0000] "GET /;jsessionid=A0B555C3A18377D993B97D4491DD1012 HTTP/1.1" 200 10311
119.63.196.45 - - [24/Aug/2011:07:05:10 +0000] "GET /;jsessionid=A3782FA61558BF11C4D5AC4F3DD1EC86 HTTP/1.1" 200 10311
119.63.196.23 - - [24/Aug/2011:07:05:53 +0000] "GET /;jsessionid=A3AF84EF13F21492EB47FAB001A1C2E5 HTTP/1.1" 200 10311
119.63.196.120 - - [24/Aug/2011:07:06:31 +0000] "GET /;jsessionid=A7C490CEC2C7F2969772AC4050C6D761 HTTP/1.1" 200 10311
119.63.196.108 - - [24/Aug/2011:07:07:07 +0000] "GET /;jsessionid=A7F769D354CB37E99843292D650D6367 HTTP/1.1" 200 10311

No one individual IP is clobbering the site, but the collective requests from this IP range are racking up active sessions.  And they seem to do it in somewhat of a coordinated fashion as one page at a time will get targeted and receive ~30 hits by ~30 different in the 119.63.196.* IP range over a 20 minute period.  Then it'll move on to another page... and this is going on pretty much all day and racking up Tomcat sessions.

I do have inactive session timeout set pretty high (720 minutes), and maybe I need to bring that number down a lot.  Maybe Baidu Japan is doing frequent checks because it thinks the page has changed due to a change in the link (i.e., the jsessionid is always different)?

Thanks for reading.  I welcome any/all suggestions!

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spiders do indeed usually not maintain a session with the website. That's normal. You should ask yourself if it is really necessary if your website creates a session upon a normal GET request. Sessions are usually used to store the logged-in user, its preferences such as locale, etcetera. But spiders do not login at all and they do not submit any forms at all. Why would you create the session then?

There are basically 2 ways to solve this "problem":

1. Fix your website so that it doesn't unnecessarily create sessions as long as there's no need to. Create it only once an user logs in or creates/updates a sessionwide preference/variable. How exactly to do it depends on the APIs/frameworks used by your website.
2. Block (specific) spiders by [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard).

Note that session creation and the session itself are not particularly expensive. An empty session object should not allocate more than 1KB. I find your session timeout however too high. The default of 30 minutes is already relatively a lot. As a completely different alternative, you could also set it to 5 minutes or something and introduce a JS/Ajax "heartbeat" which sends every timeout-1 minutes a poll request with the session cookie whenever the user is active on the document (click, keypress, etc). This would keep the session at the server alive. You can find an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319020/mvc-with-jquery-handling-session-expire/2319211#2319211).

Comment: Great food for thought, BC.

I believe I have a valid reason for using a session for non-logged in users right off the home page (I'm creating a dynamic poll in such a way that it can't be easily gamed), so I'll probably have to stick w/that approach; a cookie won't work for this unfortunately.  I can explain more if you're really curious.  (cont.)

Comment: A day or so before my initial post I actually put in a robots entry for Baiduspider to disallow everything (I.e., '/'), but I continued to see 'Baiduspider' (user agent) coming through in my logs, so I thought they weren't respecting my robots.txt.  However, starting about 2 days ago the hits from that IP range stopped entirely.  So maybe this spider is legit afterall.  I figure I'll remove that entry at some point and see what happens.  As a consequence my active sessions are way down. (cont.)

Comment: Just put that poll in a POST form and create session only when that has been submitted for first time. Spiders really don't run POST forms or something.

Comment: I went w/the high session timeout because I like how sites like Gmail keep me logged in well over 24 hours w/o activity.  The Ajax heartbeat is definitely an interesting approach.  Also, knowing an empty session obj is so small is encouraging.  I can keep it pretty lean for my site.

Anyway, I really appreciate the info!  Lots of good nuggets to consider.

Thanks! Eric

Comment: Gmail (actually, all Google sites) uses a long-living cookie which is completely separate from the session cookie. If Gmail retrieves a request with the cookie while there's no session, it will just create the session and automatically login the user based on the encrypted cookie value. See also this answer for the background details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185951/java-how-do-i-keep-a-user-logged-into-my-site-for-months/2186072#2186072

Comment: Accepted!

Good point on the POST approach; I'm *usually* very religious about using GET and POST correctly.  However, I went with GET (i.e., a regular <a> tag) because the user actually clicks on an image to submit their vote - you can see it [here](http://www.tehfaces.com)), and I believe I initially didn't want a FORM that had to rely on any JavaScript or fancy CSS to make it work as a POST.  But I'm going to rethink that now.

Thanks also for the "long-living cookie" idea.  That thought never occurred to me.

I appreciate all the great advice/ideas!  Eric

Comment: You can use an `<input type="image">` to make a clickable image which POSTs.

Comment: @Kevin: Can. But that element has actually a bit different purpose (image map; it sends x and y position of the mouse pointer), a `<input type="submit">` with a CSS background image is more common practice.

Answer (score 5):

Tomcat 7 can prevent the creation of thousands of sessions if you configure the `CrawlerSessionManagerValve`. There's a short [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Crawler_Session_Manager_Valve).

In addition, you might want to consider to prevent Tomcat from putting the session ID into the URL because it would then show up in the search engines. Again starting with Tomcat 7, you can configure this:

```
<session-config>
   <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```