# How to handle Code Error 500 in Richfaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces, myfaces

I'm using Richfaces 3.2.2 and need to show the user the 500 error page when there is Exception. The issue is that when I use ajax event I can't show the user the 500 error when there is an Exception. I've already defined the error page on web.xml.

Excuse My English. Any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using probably JSF1.2 and not JSF2, you can use `FaceletViewHandler` to handle the exceptions.

```
public class CustomViewHandler extends FaceletViewHandler {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void handleRenderException(FacesContext context, Exception ex) throws IOException, ELException,
        FacesException {
        try {
            ..

            getSessionMap().put("GLOBAL_ERROR", ex);
            getHttpResponseObject().sendRedirect("/error.jsf");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.fatal("Couldn't redirect to error page", e);
        }
    }
}
```

of course, you need to handle it in the bean, just extract the exception from session:

```
Throwable ex = (Exception) getSessionMap().remove("GLOBAL_ERROR");
```

Comment: you are welcome. please mark my answer with V (green) below the 1 number

Answer (score 4):

Check the [RichFaces developer guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html) chapter 5.10.1.

> ### [5.10.1 Request Errors Handling](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#RequestErrorsHandling)
>
> To execute your own code on the client in case of an error during Ajax request, it's necessary to redefine the standard "A4J.AJAX.onError" method:
>
> ```
> A4J.AJAX.onError = function(req, status, message){
>     window.alert("Custom onError handler "+message);
> }
> ```
>
> The function defined this way accepts as parameters:
>
> - `req` - a params string of a request that calls an error
> - `status` - the number of an error returned by the server
> - `message` - a default message for the given error
>
> Thus, it's possible to create your own handler that is called on timeouts, internal server errors, and etc.

So, to **display** the server-generated error response, you'd like to do the following:

```
A4J.AJAX.onError = function(req, status, message){
    document.open();
    document.write(req.responseText);
    document.close();
}
```

To **redirect** to the error page, do as follows:

```
A4J.AJAX.onError = function(req, status, message){
    window.location = 'error.jsf';
}
```

You'll only need to pass mandatory error details as request parameter or let the server side store it in the session as Odelya suggested.

#### Related question:

- [Handling of HTTP 4nn/5nn errors in jQuery's ajax requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738785/handling-of-server-side-http-4nn-5nn-errors-in-jquerys-ajax-requests)