# Replace current page with ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page with a dialog window which sends ajax post data to server and receives a response. During development, there can be two responses - one regular (this is not the question) or one with an error. Server returns code 500 and a page with lot of debug informations. This is a regular page returned from a framework and contains some javascript code. I want to be able to display this error page in case it happens.

The problem is, I can not simply attach the returned result to body element or open a new link in a new page and load this error again. I simply get a html page instead of data and I have to display the page (in current window or in another one).

I am using jQuery.

Comment: Please read it carefully. It is not text what I get with the error, it is whole html page I need to display. No text, no changes, no extraction just regular html page with some javascript functionality (defined in head section of returned code). I need to replace current page with this one or create new window with returned html code (head section too, not body section only)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Configure jQuery ajax setup as follows:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: handleXhrError
});
```

where `handleXhrError` function look like this:

```
function handleXhrError(xhr) {
    document.open();
    document.write(xhr.responseText);
    document.close();
}
```

#### See also:

- [Handling of server-side HTTP 4nn/5nn errors in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738785/handling-of-server-side-http-4nn-5nn-errors-in-jquerys-ajax-requests)

Comment: Yes, this is the right solution for replacing current page with html from ajax request.

Comment: Sir ! ... you saved me a lot of times on SO.

Answer (score 3):

You may also try to use data URL's, the latest versions of the major browsers supporting it:

```
function utf8_to_b64( str ) {
    return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( str )));
}

function loadHtml(html)
{
    localtion.href='data:text/html;base64,'+utf8_to_b64(html);
}
```

This way, you can load any html page you want in runtime.

Comment: unlike other answers, an approach NOT using document.write(); though slower in performance. upvoted.

Comment: Unfortunately, this no longer seems to work in FF for html containing links, since data urls no longer inherit the security context. For details,see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs#Security) (though the note only refers to data uris in the browser's location bar, this also seems to apply to the technique you've suggested [which I still upvoted for its elegance] ). Possibly I'm missing something evident ...

Answer (score 2):

In your ajax callback:

```
success: function (data) {
   $("html").html($(data).find("html").html());
}
```

That will replace the entire page's HTML content with the one received from your AJAX request. Works in Chrome... not sure about IE.

Despite that, I'm not sure why you'd want to include the `<head>` section... but you can easily modify the above to display just what's in the body of the AJAX response, and append it to a div or even a lightbox. Much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to change either if the response is a url or a html content (using django\php)

```
        var xmlhttp;
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            var replace_t = '{{ params.replace_t }}';
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                if(replace_t == 'location')
                    window.location.replace(xmlhttp.responseText);
                else if(replace_t == 'content')
                {
                    document.open();
                    document.write(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    document.close();
                } 
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET",SOME_ASYNC_HANDLER_URL,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution. I don't know if it si correct, but for Opera and Firefox it is working.

```
var error_win = window.open(
   '',
   'Server error',
   'status=0,scrollbars=1, location=0'
);
error_win.document.write(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
```

Comment: The only drawback of this approach is that the onload event isn't fired but it is still better than nothing

Comment: My code is not ok, missing error_win.document.close(). After that, the onload event is fired and the page works as it should

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just simply creating an element and inserting the returned error page into the element?  I do this with error pages and jQuery.

```
    var errorContainer = $( '<div/>' );
    errorContainer.html( errorTextResponse );
    errorContainer.appendTo( $( 'body' ) );
```

Comment: What will happen to the head section of the page I need to display? Head section loads javascript and css files

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding, but do you know what elements from the result you specifically want to display? You could trying something like this:

```
  success: function(data){
               //store the response
               var $response=$(data);
               //use .find() to locate the div or whatever else you need
               var errorMessage = $response.find('#warning').text();
               alert(errorMessage);      
            }
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to do that. Iframes are meant for loading other pages and there's no other sandbox in which to dump a standalone page -- that's what frames were designed for.

It might be difficult with the framework you're using, but it's probably worthwhile to have it generate different errors for your Ajax requests. My Ajax pages will only ever send

```
{"exit": 1, "message": "As in the shell, a non-zero exit is an error and this is why..."}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out
as easy as

```
document.body.innerHTML = YourAjaxrequest.responseText;
```

_______________________________________________^ up here is what over writes your current HTML page with the response.

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 1) {
        document.getElementById('sus').innerHTML = "SENDING.......";
    } 
      if (request.readyState == 3){
        document.getElementById('sus').innerHTML = "SENDING >>>>>>>>>>>>>";

    }

     if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {

        //document.getElementById('sus').innerHTML = request.responseText;

    document.body.innerHTML = request.responseText;


     }
  }
   request.send(formD);



  },false);
```