# Binding tab-specific data to an HTTP GET request

Tags: html, ajax, rest, http, cookies

I'm trying to implement an authentication mechanism where each browser tab may be logged in as a different user.

Here are the rules of this system:

- An authentication token indicates which user is logged in.
- There are 2 kinds of authentication tokens: private and public.
- Each private token is bound to a single tab and determines its account information.
- The public token may be read/written to by any tab and indicates the last account that was logged into (across all tabs).
- When a user logs out in any tab, both the private and public tokens are removed.
- Each time a tab hits a page that requires authentication, the system tries reading the private token. If it is not set (as in the case of a new/blank tab), it tries copying the value of the public token into the private token. If the public token is not set then the user is redirected to an authentication screen.
- When a tab is already logged in and a user clicks on a link, the request must include the private token in a custom HTTP header. Sending this information in the URI is not an option, for security reasons.
- Ability to navigate using the back/forward button the same as you would for normal links (meaning, no prompts to re-submit form data).

What I've tried so far:

- Using `cookies` for both the private and public tokens: this doesn't work because the server has no way of knowing which cookie to look in. If a user clicks on a link from inside a tab, the request sends all cookies across all tabs and the server has no way of knowing which one clicked on the link.
- Storing private tokens in `sessionStorage`: This doesn't work because when a user clicks on a link, there is no way to specify custom headers that should be sent alongside the HTTP GET request.
- Requesting the page using AJAX, then navigating to the page in memory using Data URIs: For security reasons, Internet Explorer doesn't allow the use of DATA URIs for HTML content. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- Using `<form method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">` and passing the token using hidden fields: enctype="multipart/form-data" is only supported for POST.
- Using `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` and passing the token using hidden fields: in theory, this should work but now the user gets prompted to re-submit form data if he uses the back/forward button.
- Requesting the page using AJAX, then rewriting the current page using `document.open(); document.write(); document.close()`. I tried both https://stackoverflow.com/a/4404659/14731 and http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=5767285&sid=d6a5a2e8e311598cdbad124e277e0f52#p5767285 and in both cases the scripts in the new `<head>` block never gets executed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Okay, after going through many different iterations, here is the implementation we ended up with:

### Variables

- There are two kind of data stores:

  - [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), which is shared across all tabs.
  - [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) which is unique per tab.
- We store the following variables:

  - IndexedDB contains `publicToken`, `nextTabId`.
  - sessionStorage contains `privateToken`, `tabId`.

### publicToken, privateToken

- See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1592572/14731 for a definition of an authentication token.
- There are two kinds of authentication tokens: public and private.
- `publicToken` is the token returned by the last login operation, across all tabs.
- `privateToken` is the token returned by the last login operation of the current tab.

### tabId

- Each tab is uniquely identified by a token called `tabId`.
- `nextTabId` is a number that is accessible across all tabs.
- If a tab does not have an id, it creates a new one based on `nextTabId` and increments its value.
- For example, `tabId` could have a value of "com.company.Tab`X`" where `X` is the number returned by `nextTabId`.

### Login/Logout

- Every time a tab logs in, `privateToken` and `publicToken` are overwritten using the authentication token returned by the server.
- When a user logs out, we delete `privateToken` and `publicToken` on the browser side, and `privateToken` on the server side. We do not delete `publicToken` on the server side.
- This means that anytime a tab logs out, all all tabs sharing the same `privateToken` will get logged out as well. Any tabs using a different token will be unaffected.
- When do multiple tabs share the same `privateToken`? When you open a link in a new window or tab, it inherits the `privateToken` of the parent tab.
- If we were to delete `publicToken` on the server, a tab logging out with `privateToken` X, `publicToken` Y would cause tabs with `privateToken` Y to get logged out (which is undesirable).

### On page load

- Scan the page for HTML links.
- For each link, append a `tabId` query parameter to the URL. The parameter value is equal to the value of `tabId`.
- Strip the `tabId` URL parameter from the current page using [history.replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState()_method) so users can share links with their friends (`tabId` is user-specific and cannot be shared).
- Delete the `tabId` cookie (more on this below).

### When a link is clicked

- The tab creates a `tabId` cookie and follows the link.
- The cookie has a name equal to the value of `tabId` and a value equal to the value of `privateToken`

### When a server receives a request

- If the `tabId` parameter is missing, then redirect the browser to `GetTabId.html?referer=X` where `X` is the current URL.
- If `tabId` is present but the authentication token is invalid or expired, then redirect the browser to the login screen.

### GetTabId.html

- If the tab does not have a `privateToken`, copy `publicToken` into `privateToken`.
- If both `privateToken` and `publicToken` are undefined, redirect to the login page.
- The page takes a URL parameter called `referer` which indicates where to redirect to on success.
- If the tab has a `privateToken`, append the `tabId` parameter to the `referer` page and redirect back to it.
- Use `window.location.replace()` when redirecting to remove `GetTabId.html` from the browser history.

### Why do we keep on deleting/adding cookies?

- We try to minimize the number of cookies sent to the server on each request.
- If we did not delete the `tabId` cookie on page load, then each time a tab would make a request all of the other tabs' cookies would get sent as well.

### Known issues

- "View Source" opens the URL missing `tabId`. As result, it gets the source-code of the page which redirects to `GetTabId.html` instead of the actual page.
- Awkwardly long page reloads (client is redirected to `GetTabId.html` and back to the original page).

Apologies for the long implementation details, but I could not find an easier/shorter solution.