# When navigating between webpages, display an exit animation, and preload the next page

Tags: jquery, html, http, preloading

My client wants an animation if you go from webpage A to webpage B. The animation is located on page A (its jquery/css).

They want the animation to finish (takes ~900msecs) before page B shows.

I want to use the passing time (~900msecs) to *preload* page B.

Preferably, page B really is a different page; not something I load with ajax and insert into the html dom. So ideally, I preload something and by the time I go there, the webbrowser understands it can use the preloaded version without doing any new http requests (for the html page itself at least).

I could start trying things with jquery's cache; or iframes; or data uris, and closely watch the http requests. But are there already tested and tried methods around ?

Comment: Can only do this in same page. Can't `preload` a new page

Comment: You can however have a single page app (SPA) that does client side url routing

Comment: No, as I mentioned, I dont want it SPA. If I cant fully preload it, at least I can optimize the request eg by filling the browser cache.

Comment: The only acceptable spa solution would be to load an iframe and display it fullscreen at a certain moment, but i dislike that idea.

Comment: Why are you so against an SPA when it is the best solution for what your client is asking for? Huge apps get written in SPA's these days

Comment: .. because of reasons. its part of the question, a non-spa solution please.

Comment: there isn't one that won't require putting the page into iframe or into the DOM but that won't stop browser making all the same requests and the time may not even be enough to get a lot of it cached

Answer (score 0):

YMMV, and certainly not crossbrowsertested, but you can apparently just load ajax and replace the current document with the loaded data:
[Replace current page with ajax content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387688/replace-current-page-with-ajax-content)

So .. the readable version would be

```
var newpage = '';

function danceAndLoad(url) {
    loadNewPage(url);
    while (!newpage) dance();
    insertNewPage();
}

function loadNewPage(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url
    }).done(function( data ) {

        // add a base href if needed
        newpage=data.replace('<head>','<head><base href="'+canonize(url)+'/" />');

    });



}

function insertNewPage() {

    document.open();
    document.write(newpage);
    document.close();

    // rewrite history if needed
    var ttltag = data.substring(data.indexOf("<title"), data.indexOf("</title>") + 8);
    var ttlm = /title>([^<]*)</gi.exec(ttltag);
    var title = (ttlm)?ttlm[1]:'';
    window.history.pushState(null, title, canonize(url));
    window.onpopstate=function(evt) {
        document.location.reload()
    };

}
```

Any comments or improvements are welcome