# Redirect after posting form using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Following scenario. I have a simple login-form for username and password.
Wher the user clicks the login-button the form is posted to the server which is checking the credentials. When they are okay, a redirect is made to the default landing-page.

For sending the form-data I have written the following:

```
static async postData<TResult>(options: { method: string, url: string, data?: any }): Promise<TResult> {
    return new Promise<TResult>((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onload = (): void => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        resolve(xhr.response);
                    } else {
                        reject(xhr.status);
                    }
                }
            };

            xhr.withCredentials = true;
            xhr.open(options.method, options.url, true);
            xhr.send(options.data);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        } 
    });
}
```

which is called like:

```
const response = await postData({ method: theForm.method, url: theForm.action, data: formData })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(reason => {
        console.error(reason);
    });
```

In Chrome and Firefox the response has an `responseURL`-property which I could use for setting `window.location.url = xhr.responseURL;` to redirect the page. But this wont work in IE as the response-type is something completely other.
On the other hand I have the complete HTML (which is the content of the redirect aka the landing-page) in xhr.responseText but I have no idea how I can use this?

I tried to replace the page-content as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387688/replace-current-page-with-ajax-content) But this is throwing a bunch of errors in Chrome and IE it's not working at all showing

> SCRIPT70: Permission denied

Some additional notes. I am using `TypeScript` to write the client-code which is targeted to es6 and afterwards transpiled using `babel-loader` to es5 via `webpack`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need try next code:

```
    location.href = 'http://www.example.com' or 
    location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org"); // or
    location = "http://www.mozilla.org";
```